# How to update terminal services client

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp, service, terminal

Currently running 5.2 on Server2003 R2 with XP SP2 & SP3 workstations that connect to it. Do the workstations have to use the updated (6.0) to be compatible? Will it mess with everyone's connection if I do the update while they are logged on? Reason for update is that people are complaining to me about grid lines that sometimes appear on the screen, researched that, and updating RDP client is my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use WSUS to update the client? Failing that I'd be inclined to run the update through either GPO or logon scripts. As for the version required, even the version that came with the original release of XP still works fine, albeit lacking some features.

Comment: Is there a script available to run the update for xp machines on all workstations and manually update the server os?

Comment: This kind of thing is most easily handled through WSUS, which you really should be running, if only to make your own job easier. Although there are many scripts available I can't offer you any links I have at the moment because my normal machine is currently inoperative.

Comment: Here's a link to the XP RDP7 Update: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=72158b4e-b527-45e4-af24-d02938a95683&displaylang=en